# Isolating a screencapture function

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm very beginner in flutter, and tried to use chatgpt with helping with that but no success.
I'm trying to take several screenshots of a video player that is running, like 1000.
The problem is capturing and playing the same video, lags the system.

That's why I thought about isolating the capture into an isolate.

The problem is I get exception like the following

```
E/flutter (24730): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: object is unsendable - Library:'dart:async' Class: _AsyncCompleter@4048458 (see restrictions listed at SendPort.send() documentation for more information)
```

Here is my attempt

```
 void startCaptureAndConvertToImage() async {
    setState(() {
      _takingScreenshot = true;
      _conversionReady = false;
    });

    final receivePort = ReceivePort();

    receivePort.listen((message) {
      if (message is bool && message) {
        setState(() {
          _conversionReady = true;
          _takingScreenshot = false;
        });
      }
    });

    await Isolate.spawn(
      isolateFunction,
      IsolateData(globalKey, receivePort.sendPort),
    );
  }

  void isolateFunction(IsolateData isolateData) {
    final GlobalKey globalKey = isolateData.key;
    SendPort sendPort = isolateData.sendPort;

    int a = 0;

    Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 20), (timer) async {
      a = a + 1;

      var findRenderObject = globalKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject();
      if (findRenderObject == null) {
        return;
      }
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = findRenderObject as RenderRepaintBoundary;

      /// List
      // Simulate captureIntoImage and replace with your actual logic
      // await convertIntoImage(boundary);

      if (a > 100) {
        sendPort.send(true);
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
  }
```

and here is the original function

```
 Future<void> captureAndConvertToImage() async {
    takingScreenshot.value = true;
    var a = 0;
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 20), (timer) async {
      a = a + 1;

      /// List
      var findRenderObject = globalKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject();
      if (findRenderObject == null) {
        return null;
      }
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
      findRenderObject as RenderRepaintBoundary;

      await convertIntoImage(boundary);

      if (a > 3000) {
        conversionReady.value = true;
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });

  }
```